# Bootstrap responsive table with a floating table header

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The table header works well on a large screen size device like pc or labtop but it does not work well on a mobile device, which the header's width does not follow the body's width. I have been looking for a solution for weeks but still can't get one. I hope that someone can give me clues. My attempt so far:

```js
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
  $(".persist-area").each(function() {

    var el = $(this),
      offset = el.offset(),
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

    if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "visible"
      });
    } else {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
      });
    };
  });
}

//DOM Ready
$(function() {

  var clonedHeaderRow;

  $(".persist-area").each(function() {
    clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
    clonedHeaderRow
      .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
      .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
      .addClass("floatingHeader");

  });

  $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

```css
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.maintblheadstart {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #1e3b74;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #989898;
  border-right: 0px solid #989898;
  border-top: 1px solid #989898;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989898;
}

.maintblheadend {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #1e3b74;
  padding: 5px;
  border-left: 1px solid #989898;
  border-right: 1px solid #989898;
  border-top: 1px solid #989898;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989898;
}

.maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  border-left: 1px solid #989898;
  border-right: 0px solid #989898;
  border-top: 0px solid #989898;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #989898;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.subtblhead {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #989898;
}

.subtbldata {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="persist-area" border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
      <thead>
        <tr class="persist-header">
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="3%">Column 1</th>
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="20%">Column 2</th>
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="20%">Column 3</th>
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="18%">Column 4</th>
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="20%" colspan="4">
            <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="subtblhead" colspan="4">TARGET</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="subtbldata" width="25%" nowrap="nowrap">Q1</th>
                  <th class="subtbldata" width="25%" nowrap="nowrap">Q2</th>
                  <th class="subtbldata" width="25%" nowrap="nowrap">Q3</th>
                  <th class="subtbldata" width="25%" nowrap="nowrap">Q4</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </th>
          <th class="maintblheadstart" width="4%">Column 6</th>
          <th class="maintblheadend" width="15%">Column 7</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">1.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">2.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">3.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">4.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.1.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.1.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.1.3</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.1.4</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">6.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">7.1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">1.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">3.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">4.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.3</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.4</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">6.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">7.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">1.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">3.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">4.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.3</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.4</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">6.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">7.2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">1.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">3.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">4.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.1</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.3</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">5.2.4</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">6.2</td>
          <td class="maintbldatastartSpecialColumn2" valign="top" align="center">7.2</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help provided is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with your JavaScript... but if you remove your JavaScript entirely, your table header functions as expected,

Comment: @ObsidianAge if I remove the JS, isn't that the table will not fix at the top when I scroll down?

Comment: Then just add `position: fixed`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge but then, on a mobile device or in a responsive screen, table header width will change differently has compared to table body. What to do then?